# SVN - Git migration issue error

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm migrating SVN to Git by using below command:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout //url
```

I'm getting below error:

```
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/.git/svn/refs/remotes/origin/Fortify Issues Fix and Clean up./index.lock': No such file or directory
write-tree: command returned error: 128
```

I tried creating `Fortify` folder manually but it didn't worked and tried creating `./index.lock` file and deleted still I'm facing same issue.

Comment: Do you have a branch named "Fortify Issues Fix and Clean up." complete with the dot on the end? Try renaming it to something without the dot or spaces like "FortifyIssuesFixAndCleanUp". I suspect git-svn got sloppy about directories with spaces and special characters in them.

Comment: Yeah, try renaming the branch in SVN to one with no dot and no spaces.

Comment: I just got same error after waiting for 30 mins :)

Comment: Oh, this is SVN. The old branch name will still be in the history. You might have to skip that branch with `--ignore-paths`. Or find a way to make `git-svn` rename that branch.

Comment: Can you please share me full command like  **git svn clone --stdlayout URL** for ignoring branch.

Comment: It's gonna be something like `--ignore-paths='^/branches/Fortify Issues Fix and Clean up'`

Comment: I already renamed branch name and removed all the spaces and dot. **--ignore-paths='^/branches/FortifyIssuesFixandCleanup'**

Comment: Renaming the branch won't work, sorry. I've been using Git so long I forgot how SVN works. Renaming a branch in SVN changes the name it has *right now* but `git-svn` is converting *the entire history*. In history, it will still have the name `Fortify Issues Fix and Cleanup.`.

Comment: Is this a one-time conversion and after that you are using only Git or do you want to commit back Git commits to the SVN repository?

Comment: This is only one time converstion from SVN to GIT

Answer (score -2):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will easily be able to set up the rules file so that exactly your branch and its history will get migrated.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though git-svn is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

---

Also with the `svn2git` tool I recommend you have the same problem, that spaces are not allowed in Git branch names, but you can easily mitigate it with a name substitution like

```
substitute branch s/ /_/
```

to replace spaces by underscores.

So as a complete match rule for the standard layout this could for example look like

```
match /branches/([^/]+)/
    repository myproject
    branch \1
    substitute branch s/ /_/
end match
```